# Using jsdom and update at every POST Request Variable with elements, but doesnt work

Tags: node.js, jsdom

i have the problem, that my response function doesnt update the Variable, which takes an element out of an file:

Post Function:

```
app.post("/profile", function(req, res) {
var id = req.body.playerid;
request("https://statsroyale.com/profile/" + id).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('stats.html'));
var wins1 = document.getElementsByClassName('statistics__metricCounter ui__headerExtraSmall statistics__trophyMetric');
var wins = wins1[0].innerHTML;
res.render("profile", {person: id, wins: wins}); });
```

jsdom.env function(which sets the file onetime at the beginning):

```
jsdom.env({
file: 'stats.html',
done: function (err, window) {
    GLOBAL.window = window;
    GLOBAL.document = window.document;
}
```

});

But then, if i request an other id, it shows me the old element

SRC:

```
 var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require("request")
var fs = require("fs");
var $ = require("jquery");
var jsdom
try {
  jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js"); // jsdom >= 10.x
  const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
} catch (e) {
  jsdom = require("jsdom"); // jsdom <= 9.x
  const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
}
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});
app.post("/profile", function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.playerid;
    jsdom.JSDOM.fromURL("https://statsroyale.com/profile/" + id).then(dom => {
      var wins1 = dom.window.document.getElementsByClassName('statistics__metricCounter ui__headerExtraSmall statistics__trophyMetric');
      var wins = wins1[0].innerHTML;
      res.render("profile", {person: id, wins: wins});
    });
});
app.get("/profile", function(req, res) {
    var id = req.query.playerid;
    res.render("profile", {person: id});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Don't do that `try catch`. I don't know who told you to do that, but that prevents you from accessing the `fromURL` convenience method. Just do `var jsdom = require('jsdom');`

Comment: Nice works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up your `jsdom` environment only occurs once. You'd need to use [`fs.watchFile()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) to keep track of any changes that occur to the file and re-initialize the environment each time that callback is invoked. In addition, you'll need to make sure that

```
var wins1 = document.getElementsByClassName('statistics__metricCounter ui__headerExtraSmall statistics__trophyMetric');
var wins = wins1[0].innerHTML;
res.render("profile", {person: id, wins: wins}); });
```

isn't invoked until after the asynchronous `pipe` completes and `jsdom` is re-initialized with the updated file.

#### Update

Even easier, instead of using a global `dom` initialized from the local HTML file, [you can invoke `jsdom` directly from the URL](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#fromurl):

```
jsdom.JSDOM.fromURL("https://statsroyale.com/profile/" + id, options).then(dom => {
  var wins1 = dom.window.document.getElementsByClassName('statistics__metricCounter ui__headerExtraSmall statistics__trophyMetric');
  var wins = wins1[0].innerHTML;
  res.render("profile", {person: id, wins: wins});
});
```

Comment: Nice one, Thank you !

Comment: But it shows, that there isnt any method like fromURL()... I dont know what to do

Comment: If i could ask one thing: Why does my server lag, if i want to split the string?
src:
https://jsfiddle.net/quy0w90v/

Comment: I would imagine your server is crashing, not lagging. You call `.substring(...)` on `dom.window.document.getElementsByClassName(...)`, which isn't a string.